# How do I execute this GROUP BY mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a table called "Fruits" with a column called "name".

```
name
--------
apple
orange
orange
orange
apple
grape
```

How can I execute a query to produce this:

```
orange   3
apple    2
grape    1
```

(Group by the name, and then sort them by their count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY name
ORDER by cnt DESC
```